# Python morse code pausing

Tags: python, morse-code

I'm trying to figure out how to make my program pause. The method `encodeMesssage` is working fine and turns each letter into it's corresponding Morse code letter. Once it reaches the end of a letter it turns gives a letter pause `[lpause]`. Then after it finishes a complete word it will give a word pause `[wpause]`.

My second method is supposed to turn this message into actually sounds with the windsound module. The beeps are working fine, my problem is that I can't seem to get the `[lpause]` and `[wpause]` to behave.

`morseCode = {'A':'.-','B':'-..','C':'-.-.','D':'-..','E':'.', 'F':'..-.','G':'--.','H':'....','I':'..','J':'.---', 'K':'-.-.','L':'.-..','M':'--','N':'-.','O':'---', 'P':'.--.','Q':'--.-','R':'.-.','S':'...','T':'-', 'U':'..-','V':'...-','W':'.--','X':'-..-','Y':'-.--', 'Z':'--..','1':'.----','2':'..---','3':'...--', '4':'....-','5':'.....','6':'-....','7':'--...', '8':'---..','9':'----.','0':'-----' }`

```
def encodeMessage(m):
    message = m.upper().strip()
    encodedMessage =''
    isInWord = False

    for ch in message:
        if isInWord:
            if ch in morseCode:
                encodedMessage += '[lpause]'+ morseCode[ch]
            else:
                encodedMessage += '[wpause]'
                isInWord = False
       else: # not in word
            if ch in morseCode:
                encodedMessage +=  morseCode[ch]
                isInWord = True
            else:
                pass    # nothing to do
    return encodedMessage

def sendMoreCodedMessage(message):
    for ch in message:
        if ch == '.':
            winsound.Beep(200, 100)
        elif ch == '-':
            winsound.Beep(370, 100)
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
return None
```

here is an example of the output from `encodeMessage` 
....[lpause].[lpause]-.--[wpause]-.[lpause]---[lpause].--[wpause]-.--[lpause]--‌​-[lpause]..-[wpause].-[wpause]-..[lpause].-.[lpause]---[lpause].--[lpause]-.[wpau‌​se]-.-.[lpause]---[lpause].--' –

Comment: You should add that extra info in the question text, not as a comment.

Comment: _"my problem is that I can't seem to get the [lpause] and [wpause] to behave."_ <-- This is very vague information. Can you describe the desired and actual behaviour in detail?

Comment: Yes, the [lpause] is supposed to pause maybe for 1 second and then the for loop should continue to execute . and - beeps. Then it should pause for a word [wpause] for about 3 seconds to distinguish in between the 2. However, at the moment I have lpause and wpause working on the same time of 1 seconds.. except they are pausing for each individual letter in the phrase [lpause].. For example ..-[ pause l pause p pause a pause u pause s pause e pause. I want it to take [lpause] as a whole and make it pause instead of letter by letter.. so if it read [lpause] pause then it continues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should probably use one-character identifiers for your letter and word pauses, since you use per-character checks to figure out what sound to make.  I have replaced the pause identifiers with 'l' and 'w', and adjusted your SendMoreCodedMessage function accordingly:

```
def encodeMessage(m):
    message = m.upper().strip()
    encodedMessage =''
    isInWord = False

    for ch in message:
        if isInWord:
            if ch in morseCode:
                encodedMessage += 'l'+ morseCode[ch]
            else:
                encodedMessage += 'w'
                isInWord = False
       else: # not in word
            if ch in morseCode:
                encodedMessage +=  morseCode[ch]
                isInWord = True
            else:
                pass    # nothing to do
    return encodedMessage

def sendMoreCodedMessage(message):
    for ch in message:
        if ch == '.':
            winsound.Beep(200, 100)
        elif ch == '-':
            winsound.Beep(370, 100)
        elif ch == 'w':
            time.sleep(3)
        elif ch == 'l':
            time.sleep(1)

    return None
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes more sense to me. My instructor included the long phrases and they were sorta nonsensical to me. Thanks for the help!